# Display 0 for rows with no data

Tags: mysql, sql

The Query below displays records for 5 Dashboards. The query works fine. But it displays only those Dashboards for which data exists. What I want to do is, it should display all the Dashboards and the columns for which data does not exist, it should display 0 or NULL.

```
    Select 
b.[path],
count(*) as "No of Calls",
a.TimeDataRetrieval as "DB Retrieval time",
a.TimeProcessing as "Processing time",
a.TimeRendering as "Rendering Time"

FROM LogStorage a inner join Catalog b on a.[ReportID] = b.[ItemID]

where b.[path] IN ('Dashboard1','Dashboard2','Dashboard3','Dashboard4','Dashboard5')
group by b.[path]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` displays only shared records. You can do a `LEFT JOIN` instead to display all from one table and shared records when applicable.

Comment: I tried that. But it still wont show me all the dashboards. what I want is, to display all 5 dashboards all the time. and if for any corresponding dashboard, no data exists, it should display 0. In short, the column b.[path] should always show Dashboards1 to Dashboard5.

Comment: If you want to select all of the dashboards, then your `SELECT` should target that table, and you should `LEFT JOIN` on the table that has the conditional information. In your case, I believe you could even do a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part is:

```
FROM LogStorage a inner join Catalog b on a.[ReportID] = b.[ItemID]
where b.[path] IN ('Dashboard1','Dashboard2','Dashboard3','Dashboard4','Dashboard5')
```

This is restricting the result set to only records that exist in LogStorage and Catalog, irrespective of the join type.

You want to flip this around and use a left-join:

```
SELECT b.[path]
, SUM (CASE WHEN a.some_column IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as "No of Calls"
, a.TimeDataRetrieval as "DB Retrieval time"
, a.TimeProcessing as "Processing time"
, a.TimeRendering as "Rendering Time"
FROM Catalog b
LEFT JOIN LogStorage a on b.[ItemID] = a.[ReportID]
WHERE b.[path] IN ('Dashboard1','Dashboard2','Dashboard3','Dashboard4','Dashboard5')
group by b.[path]
, a.TimeDataRetrieval
, a.TimeProcessing
, a.TimeRendering
```

Also, for which table are you counting records?  It's a little ambiguous, although if I had to guess I'd say LogStorage.  In that case you'll probably want to aggregate those other LogStorage columns, as without an aggregate the output will be just be the rows and the count will be 1 for each row.

Edit: I forgot to mention, that COUNT probably needs to be a SUM CASE expression because null values are eliminated with an aggregate like this.